# Category wise COUNT DISTINCT query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN category='CAT1' THEN val END) as SUMvalCAT1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN category='CAT2' THEN val END) as SUMvalCAT2 
from TABLENAME 
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

This is a working query where I'm summing the `val` for two different `category` within groups of `col1,col2`.

Now similarly I want the Count of distinct values of another columns say `XYZ`.
So if I try:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN category='CAT1' THEN val END) as SUMvalCAT1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN category='CAT2' THEN val END) as SUMvalCAT2,
COUNT(CASE WHEN category='CAT1' THEN DISTINCT XYZ END) as CAT1dist,
COUNT(CASE WHEN category='CAT2' THEN DISTINCT XYZ END) as CAT2dist
from TABLENAME 
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

But this throws an error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT XYZ END) as CAT1dist,
COUNT(CASE WHEN category='CAT2' THEN DISTI' at line 4
```

What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

DISTINCT has to come at the beginning of the `COUNT` argument:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ... END)
```

It's a special modifier to the `COUNT` function, not something that can be applied to values arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `DISTINCT` keyword before `CASE`, like so:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN category='CAT1' THEN val END) as SUMvalCAT1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN category='CAT2' THEN val END) as SUMvalCAT2,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN category='CAT1' THEN XYZ END) as CAT1dist,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN category='CAT2' THEN XYZ END) as CAT2dist
from TABLENAME 
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2520e/1)